# UIWebView not loading content within bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` on my iPad application, which loads content in a `UIWebView` in the detail `UIViewController`. I am trying to load content from a locally stored `html` file. The problem is that the contentSize of the UIScrollView within the webView seems to extend beyond the frame of the webView. This causes the content to be scrollable sideways also, which is quite annoying. I have tried using `[[self.webView scrollView] setContentSize:CGSizeMake(w, h)];`, but this doesn't seem to be working. Has anyone faced similar problems? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See answer from Happy Coding below. it may be help you.

Comment: None of the suggestions are helping I'm afraid. The problem is that the frame of the webView is adapted to the DetailViewControler's frame, but the contentSize remains (768, 1024), or the other way around for landscape mode. Any change in frame doesn't seem to be affecting the content size.

Comment: the main thing is why you are adding scrollview in UIWebview. i am not clear on this point. because UIWebview has is own property for scrollview. Second thing what is the size in html body like height and width. can you please make me more clear on this point?

Comment: Thanks for your last comment. It got me looking into the html file and I checked the parameters for the height and width of the content and found out that the width was set to "device-width". I changed that to the appropriate value and now it works like a charm. :)

Comment: perfect Rameez. good going. don't forget to upvote on my verbal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem properly is that you are having problem with content not fit in within your UIWebView.

You may try this property of UIWebView:

```
[self webView].scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

This will fit the contents within the webView and will also enable zoom in out for users.

For more help please review apple documentation for UIWebView here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW19

Comment: If the content of the html page is bigger then the Webview frame then surely you may have horizontal/vertical scroll in the webview.

Comment: Secondly, scrollView property of UIWebView is read only. You may cannot set the content size of your own. Alternatively you may change the width and height of your html content to set it in UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

try below settings in your view controller where you initialize your UIWebview.

```
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self.webView scrollView] setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
```